# Java Map - Integer value is converted to String

Tags: java, dictionary, casting

I am totally confused - please see code below and output:

```
Map<String, Object> strObjMap= new HashMap<>();
strObjMap.put(SOME_KEY_ONE, someIntegerValue);
strObjMap.put(SOME_KEY_TWO, someIntegerValue);
System.out.println(strObjMap.get(SOME_KEY_ONE).getClass().getCanonicalName());
```

And I am getting `java.lang.String`. I have tried with both `Integer` and `int` - same result.

Could you please be so kind and explain me what is happening?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you'd show us what `someIntegerValue` is.

Comment: Testing the code you've provided indeed prints `java.lang.Integer`.  What you've provided is not what you're running, or the object you're adding is not, in fact, an integer.

Comment: @dimo414 It should print out integer indeed, and the object is Integer - it works fine if you compile it. But in my class it is outputing String. I will close question bevause I have no idea why it is happening, and thus question itself looks stupid. Probably I have missed something...

Comment: Clearly, the object you're inserting is not, in fact, an Integer.  Try to assemble an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) rather than the current half-complete snippet in the question.  Simply by creating the SSCCE you will likely find your bug.

Comment: I have found bug today - separate class was used to hold KEY String's, and somehow it had same String value for same KEY... Thus than putting Object value of String type it was overwriting Integer value. @dimo414 Thanks, you advice with SSCCE really helped! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure `someIntegerValue` is an `int`/`Integer`? Add

```
System.out.println(someIntegerValue.getClass());
```

and tell us what it outputs.

The larger issue is that your map is declared as `Map<String, Object>`. Note the value is `Object`. Thus the compiler will allow any object type to be the value, there's no compile type checking of the value. Change the declaration to `Map<String, Integer>` if your intent is to allow only integer values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am sure it is integer. Object is there for a reason - I sometimes might need value of different type.